# onResume never been called when click the phone hardware back button on android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm facing this problem I have MainActivity and SettingsPreference so i want to reload adapter on MainActivity when i return from settings to MainActivity i used onResume() it worked vary good when i click on ActionBar back button,  but when i try it on hardware back button it  it never been called ,i find out that the system calls on onPostResume() instead of onResume()  so try to use it, but the changes are never been applied

[this is the SettingsActivity i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CACa9.png)

This code works when the  ActionBar back button is pressed

```
      @Override
          protected void onResume() {
              super.onResume();
              dataFromSharedPrefrence = getSettingsSharedPreferences();
              adapterExample.notifyDataSetChanged();

          }
```

The system calls onPostResume() when hardware back button is pressed but the changes never applied

```
@Override
        protected void onPostResume() {
              super.onPostResume();
              dataFromSharedPrefrence = getSettingsSharedPreferences();
              adapterExample.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the SettingsActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
```

I find out this difference when i Override lifecycle methods

1. When ActionBar button is pressed this is the output

```
2020-05-05 06:00:44.899 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onDestroy
2020-05-05 06:00:44.907 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onDetachedFromWindow
2020-05-05 06:00:44.964 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:44.990 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:45.009 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:45.015 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:45.037 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onContentChanged
2020-05-05 06:00:45.048 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onStart
2020-05-05 06:00:45.051 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onPostCreate
2020-05-05 06:00:45.053 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onResume
2020-05-05 06:00:45.056 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onPostResume
2020-05-05 06:00:45.078 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onAttachedToWindow
2020-05-05 06:00:45.141 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:45.188 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
2020-05-05 06:00:45.223 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onCreateView
```

2. when hardware back button is pressed this is the output

```
2020-05-05 06:01:21.732 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onRestart
2020-05-05 06:01:21.734 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onStart
2020-05-05 06:01:21.738 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onResume
2020-05-05 06:01:21.739 23467-23467/com.example.test E/MainActivity: onPostResume
```

Comment: are your sure you are using activity for Settings SharedPreferences maybe your using fragment in that case `onResume()` or  `onPostResume()` never call until you come back from activity or recent screen

Comment: Yes i'm using the android studio default SettingsActivity

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Instead of using `onResume()` try `onStart()`:

```
  @Override
      protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          dataFromSharedPrefrence = getSettingsSharedPreferences();
          adapterExample.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
```

Comment: Nothing happened same problem works with ActionBar back button only.

Comment: What happens when you press the hardware back button? Do you go back?

Comment: Yes it go back to MainActivity and if i Toast or Log a message on onPostResume() it printed but the changes on the adapter never been applied and the same code on onResume() with ActionBar button  it words normally